# Is This A Deadlock - Please see code

Tags: hibernate, log4j, solaris, deadlock

is this is a deadlock? it seems to lock java.io.PrintStream a lot.
it would happen very randomly, if your would take a look. the printstream object with id 0x67804350 was locked simultaneously by same thread.

```
"service-j2ee-247" prio=5 tid=0x00ea34b0 nid=0x13b runnable [1bb2d000..1bb2f678]
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(CharBuffer.java:347)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:378)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:136)
    - locked <0x67804410> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:191)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
    - locked <0x67804410> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.PrintStream.newLine(PrintStream.java:323)
    - locked <0x67804350> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:586)
    - locked <0x67804350> (a java.io.PrintStream)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.log(AbstractBatcher.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1162)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1577)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:solaris]?

Answer (score 3):

Since `synchronized` locks are re-entrant, this isn't a deadlock. There may be a deadlock somewhere in your application, but this isn't it.

From the [concurrency tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> ## Reentrant Synchronization
>
> Recall that a thread cannot acquire a lock owned by another thread.
>   But a thread can acquire a lock that it already owns. Allowing a
>   thread to acquire the same lock more than once enables reentrant
>   synchronization. This describes a situation where synchronized code,
>   directly or indirectly, invokes a method that also contains
>   synchronized code, and both sets of code use the same lock. Without
>   reentrant synchronization, synchronized code would have to take many
>   additional precautions to avoid having a thread cause itself to block.

Comment: hi,here's the part of the code that it has. private void log(String sql) {
    SQL_LOG.debug(sql);
    if (this.factory.getSettings().isShowSqlEnabled()) System.out.println("Hibernate: " + sql);
  } after checking other locks, most of the locks are against that particular java.io.PrintStream